# Problems while deploying the MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I am getiing the error, when trying to deploy the mvc website : The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) does not have write access to '`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files`'

I have tried the following solutions ,but still getting the same error :

1. Re-installed IIS
2. Ran the following commands in cmd :

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis -ga "NT Authority\Network Service"` &

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What are you running as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems silly, but it's true. After just restarting the server, it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the application pool issue for your web app. Check if you still use ASP.Net classic or integrated pool. If so, you have to install some MVC libraries to your ISS server.